# SQL based on my Example for Month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL and Learning on my own. I was wondering if someone can help guiding me to a write SQL.

I have the below data:

[image: Sample]

I am using the following query:

```
SELECT 
    TIMESTAMP
    DATEPART(Year, TIMESTAMP) Year, 
    DATEPART(Month, TIMESTAMP) Month, 
    COUNT(*) [Total Rows]
FROM 
    stage.ACTIVITY_ACCUMULATOR_archive
WHERE 
    TIMESTAMP BETWEEN '01-Jan-2014' AND '30-June-2014'
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(Year, TIMESTAMP), DATEPART(Month, TIMESTAMP)
ORDER BY 
    Year, Month
```

What I am trying to achieve is to display the `Timestamp` with year and month between the certain date and group them by month and year.

I get an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'Year'

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: When I run the above I get an error Incorret syntax near 'Year'

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using? Also, please share the exact text of the error.

Comment: There is  a typo in your query. Change `SELECT TIMESTAMP  DATEPART(Year, TIMESTAMP) Year,` to `SELECT DATEPART(Year, TIMESTAMP) Year,`.

Comment: @Mureinik - its MS SQL Server Management Studio - the exact message is Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'Year'.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner  Thanks it worked.. but thanks to all for looking in to this :) This site is great...

Comment: A sidenote: Don't compare dates with strings. '01-Jan-2014' is a string whereas '20140101' is considered a valid ISO date literal in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.There was a extra timestamp column in select list.

```
SELECT  
    DATEPART(Year, TIMESTAMP) Year, 
    DATEPART(Month, TIMESTAMP) Month, 
    COUNT(*) [Total Rows]
FROM 
    stage.ACTIVITY_ACCUMULATOR_archive
WHERE 
    TIMESTAMP BETWEEN '01-Jan-2014' AND '30-June-2014'
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(Year, TIMESTAMP), DATEPART(Month, TIMESTAMP)
ORDER BY 
    Year, Month
```